# what is the difference between containerStyle and Style in <Map> of google-maps-react API

Tags: google-maps-react

Hi I am using this [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react) API.

From the documentation, under  tag, there is Style and ContainerStyle properties. Could anyone explain

1. what is the difference between these two; and
2. when do i use either one of it

*Extract from documentation
Style: Takes CSS style object - commonly width and height.
Container Style: Takes CSS style object - optional, commonly when you want to change from the default of position "absolute".*

Answer (score 1):

As from documenatation, It's just an attribute to change the position.

> Container Style: Takes CSS style object - optional, commonly when you
> want to change from the default of position "absolute".

Style is to change the other properties related to map.

Comment: Thank you. Is it recommended to use both? Or one only depending on whether we need to adjust the position?

Comment: You can use both...